# How to maximize the absolute value of the sum of exponential complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, nonlinear-optimization

Given the real values $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\}$ and $\{\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_d\}$, I want to solve for $x_k$ and $y_k$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ this problem:

\begin{align}\text{maximize} \quad& \left|\sum_{k=1}^ne^{j2\pi fx_k}e^{jy_k}e^{-jk\alpha(\theta)}\right|^2,\\\text{subject to } \quad & \alpha(\theta)=\pi \sin(\theta_i) \text{ for all } f\in\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\} \text{ and } i\in\{1,\ldots,d\}.\end{align}

where $j=\sqrt{-1}$.

This translates into $m$ optimization problems as follows, where problem $p$ is given by:
\begin{align} \text{maximize } & \left|\sum_{k=1}^ne^{j2\pi f_px_k}e^{jy_k}e^{-jk\alpha(\theta_i)}\right|^2,\\ \text{subject to } & \alpha(\theta_i)=\pi \sin(\theta_i),\text{ for } i\in\{1,\ldots,d\}.\end{align}

What is the best way to solve this optimization problem? Can we solve it using mathematical programming solvers?

Writing down the absolute value squared of the objective function, I find that $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^ne^{j2\pi fx_k}e^{jy_k}e^{-jk\alpha(\theta)}\right|^2=n+2\sum_{1\leq k<k'\leq n}\cos(\Phi_k-\Phi_{k'}),$$ where $\Phi_k=2\pi fx_k+y_k-k\alpha(\theta).$ What to do now?

Comment: All the exponentials lie on the unit circle. The sum is max in absolute value if all terms are in the same direction (from 0), and you control the direction of two of them with arbitrary $x_k$ and $y_k$. Just align with the third. Solutions are up to a multiple of "something" that translates as a multiple of $2\pi$ in the exponential ($2\pi$ for $y_k$, $1/f$ for $x_k$).